# How do i add text to span using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent

I am trying to add the selected value of combo box to its preceding span. but it failed too sad.
I am trying with following code:

```
<span></span><select multiple ="multiple" ondblclick="$(this).css('display','none').prev().css('display','inline').addClass('sss').html($(this).val());">....</select>
```

What's the error here? how can i do it easily?

I want it to trigger in double click event. as after double clicking on option of combo box it should disappear and selected text should appear in span

and of course i forgot to tell that my select box is not selectbox. its a lisstbox. i.e multiple="multiple"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put an `option` in your `select` tag.

```
<span></span>

<select>
    <option>Something</option>
</select>
```

js

```
$('select').click(function(){
  $(this).css('display','none')
      .prev()
      .css('display','inline')
      .addClass('sss')
      .html($(this).val());
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AKa9b/

**EDIT**

Based on the comment *not working in context of multiple option*, I revised as follows:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('select option:selected').each(function(){
       $(this).parent().css('display','none')
      .prev()
      .css('display','inline')
      .addClass('sss')
      .html($(this).val());
    });
});
```

**Second example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/AKa9b/2/

Comment: this worked perfectly. though you forgot to add multiple="multiple" on select

Comment: Glad it worked out @KoolKabin!  I've updated the example with the `multiple="multiple".  You're right about that.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```
$('select').change(
    function() {
        $(this).prev('span').addClass('sss').text($(this).val());
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M6pEc/).

References:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: Nicely done @David.  I think you are missing the `display:none` part of the script.  Looks like the OP wants to lose the `select` after a choice is made.

Comment: @JasonGennaro: yeah, I left that as exercise for the reader... =)

Comment: I want it to trigger in double click event. as after double clicking on option of combo box it should disappear and selected text should appear in span

Comment: What does a *double-click* do that a *change* event doesn't? Also, when trying to double-click an `option` the option disappears between the first and second of the clicks.

Comment: double clicking allowes user to choose option with confirmation while single click can be made to focus the object. also it should disappear once the option is selected